# Show array data like console style ["1","2","3"]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input, output

How can I show array like console.log in `<input>` ?

```
var data = ['1'];
console.log(data);
$("input").val(data+"");
```

Can I show input value like `["1"]` ?

And How can I can it back from `<input>` value to array

http://jsbin.com/uyevuj/1/edit

Comment: Try escaping html using `\\`..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `JSON.stringify`:

```
$("input").val(JSON.stringify(data)); //input will display ["1"]
```

http://jsbin.com/ijebay/6/

Here's some MDN reference for future readers: [JSON.stringify - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Edit: To "get the array" back out of the input:

```
var data = JSON.parse($("input").val());
```

Comment: @l2aelba: Note that `JSON.stringify` is not supported by IE <= 7.

Comment: Ok, I will use only in admin back-end , thanks :D @MarcelKorpel

Comment: Btw, How can I do back ? like `<input value='["1"]'>` http://jsbin.com/uyevuj/3/edit output i got `["[\"1\"]"]`

Answer (score 3):

Yup, use `JSON.stringify`:

`$("input").val(JSON.stringify(data));`

http://jsbin.com/ijebay/4